# Executing a script before shutdown on RPi3b+ running Buster

Tags: raspbian, systemd, shutdown

I am looking at executing a script on a RPi3b+ with Raspbian Buster that is copying some files located on a ramdisk to a persistent folder located on the SD Card before a shutdown or a reboot of the RPi.
I looked at topics on websites which are very close to what I am trying to do but I could not get the systemd service to execute the script at shutdown.
I currently use the following service created in */etc/systemd/system* and named *endSession.service*:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script to execute at shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target
After=basic.target

[Service]
User=pi
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/pi/noise/end_session.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After creating the service, I executed the following commands: *sudo systemctl daemon-reload* and then *sudo systemctl enable endSession.service*.
The script to execute before shutdown is named *end_session.sh* and copies a few files from a ramdisk to the */home/pi/noise* folder. The script is executable and when run as *./end_session.sh* it does what is expected. After a reboot of the RPi, I check the status of the endSession service with *sudo systemctl status endSession.service* and it shows the following:

```
* endSession.service - Script to execute at shutdown
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/endSession.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-08-20 18:05:45 CDT; 24min ago
  Process: 401 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 401 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 20 18:05:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Script to execute at shutdown...
Aug 20 18:05:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Script to execute at shutdown.
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. Any suggestions are welcome!

Best regards,

JF

Comment: Not Pi specific (hence the close vote).  Perhaps you are assuming the script is run from a particular directory and the copy paths are wrong.